# Brave or bravely?

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives

I am translating a text from English to my own language.

This is the context, my question is about the sentence in bold. 
My question is about the interpretation of a word.

> If we did not find the perfect way to start the perfect New Year and are not checking off all of our life’s goals finally this year, it is all too easy to walk in a continual cloud of defeat. Instead of living in this new life God describes, we choose the same old stumbling blocks over and over again.
>   **Yet God continuously commands us to choose brave.** He does not tell us to choose what path we want for the year; He commands us to be brave enough to choose His path with every step of our lives. Because God knows the incredible future He holds for us, He does not apologize for commanding us to follow Him.

In the sentence:

> Yet God continuously commands us to choose brave.

Am I correct in assuming that *brave* is a noun (somewhat meaning that we are commanded to choose brave things), and not an adverb beloning to the verb *choose*, because otherwise it would have said to choose brave*ly*?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the broader context.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Read the FAQ here: https://english.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @Kris Exactly so:  and that should include the sentence or two immediately following.

Comment: Obviously, *brave* is a noun here, not an adverb, so no *-ly*.

Comment: @Kris: I added the surrounding sentences

Comment: Right, *brave* is a noun here. "Yet God continuously commands us to choose (the path of the) brave," where "the path of the brave" is the object of the verb *choose*. HTH.

Comment: Brave is not a noun in this context.  The correct word would be bravery.

Answer (score 2):

*To choose brave* has become a set phrase to a certain degree, there is even a book with the title

> *[I Choose Brave: Embracing Holy Courage and Understanding Godly Fear](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/I_Choose_Brave/adbIDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)*

*Brave* is not a noun here. It is a predicative adjective of a non-finite clause which was omitted for stylistic effect:

> Yet God continuously commands us ***to choose [to be] brave***.

I know that in expressions like

> *aim big* or *aim high*

both *big* and *high* are adverbs, but I think *brave* does not belong to this category.

This is actually explained by the following passage from the text you quote:

> He commands us ***to be brave*** enough ***to choose*** His path.

Answer (score -2):

> **Brave is a noun in your sentence **

A **noun** can be the subject of a verb, the object of a verb, the complement of a verb, the object of a preposition, or an appositive. If your clause performs any of these functions it is a noun clause.

An **adverb** is anything that answers the questions where, when, why, or how. If your clause answers any of these questions it is an adverb clause.

An **adjective** gives more information about a noun. If you clause gives more information about a noun, it is an adjective clause.